# Buffering page content into variable in ASP as can be done in PHP?

Tags: php, templates, asp-classic, buffer

I am writing a simple template engine for my sister's school, and I am doing it in ASP as it's the only thing their locked-down server can run.

I would like to know whether it's possible to retrieve page template content from a template file, store the content as a variable, concatenate it and display it after performing some basic tag replacement? Examples I've seen use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to grab the page content, but I've read that this can cause thread starvation and other issues.

Server.execute appears much more efficient, but there isn't (as far as I can see) a way to buffer the output of the page that is executed into a variable on the calling page. This is trivial in PHP, I'm wondering if ASP's seeming inability to do this is due to its age and primitiveness, or whether there's some other simple way to achieve the result that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your confusion is coming from your terminology usage... while there isn't a native solution, there are a number of templating engines out there for ASP - you're just not going to find them by the term "buffering" (at least not as you've used it in your question).

There are two that spring to mind immediately:

- [KudzuASP](http://www.andrewfriedl.com/2010/02/kudzuasp-template-engine-for-asp/)
- [ASP-Ajaxed](https://code.google.com/p/asp-ajaxed/)

I've not used the former, but have heard good things about it.

As for the latter, it's a larger framework that I've taken over some maintenance/hosting for. If I ever get the spare time again, I do plan on doing some other work with it.

If you want just the templating part without the rest of the framework, [the original author posted about it on his blog](http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/06/28/template-component-for-classic-asp/).

There are some others out there, but they are generally found in larger dev frameworks like [ASP Xtreme Evolution](http://zend.lojcomm.com.br/goodies/asp-xtreme-evolution/) and [Simple MVC ASP Framework](http://robrohan.com/2006/09/19/simple-mvc-asp-framework/), not (generally) as stand-alone components.